# How to use 'less' command to read one lined long text

Tags: command-line

When I try to read long text with less command at terminal, it ends with "...". I want to see full line. I had tried searching in `man less` but I can't find how to make it.
[e.g](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JlTlV.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I misunderstood the problem you have. Your original problem is that the text output from `man -k` is truncated. This has nothing to do with the `less` command.

`man -k` is in fact the `apropos` command. So, just call the `apropos -l`, or `man -kl` instead of `man -k`.

`-l, --long
              Do not trim output to the terminal width.  Normally, output will
              be  truncated  to  the terminal width to avoid ugly results from
              poorly-written NAME sections.`

`duda@coolomet:~$ apropos python
python (1)           - an interpreted, interactive, object-oriented programmi...
python-config (1)    - output build options for python C/C++ extensions or em...
python2 (1)          - an interpreted, interactive, object-oriented programmi...`

`duda@coolomet:~$ apropos -l python
python (1)           - an interpreted, interactive, object-oriented programming language
python-config (1)    - output build options for python C/C++ extensions or embedding
python2 (1)          - an interpreted, interactive, object-oriented programming language`

Comment: Thanks you, sir. It is exactly what I want.

Answer (score 1):

This is controlled by the '-S' option.

> -S or --chop-long-lines
>
> Causes lines longer than the screen width to be chopped (truncated) rather than wrapped.  That is, the portion of a
>   long line that does not fit in the screen width is not shown.  The
>   default is to wrap long lines; that is, display the remainder on the
>   next line.

If your lines are chopped by default, then you need to update your default configuration.

Comment: Thz. Now, I know I can use -S to read long line in text file. But still cannot read full result of  "man -k". But I guess it is to do with "man -k", not "less".